# Grabbing doubles from a scanned line.

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

I am reading in a line with

```
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
       line = in.nextLine();  
    }
```

There is a line that I will encounter that starts with a "#". Once I hit this line

```
    if(line.startsWith("#")){

    }
```

I want to grab the four doubles in the line. A sample of the line looks like:

```
    # should be O: 0.00, A: 0.45, B: 0.35, AB: 0.20
```

I'm new to Java, and I was wondering if there is a way to scan through this line looking for doubles, and saving them into separate variables.

Comment: Will the input be always be in this pattern? or it may vary?

Comment: the input is always in this pattern

Comment: In that case, i have added a sample solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input="# should be O: 0.00, A: 0.45, B: 0.35, AB: 0.20";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9].[0-9]{2}");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        int i=0;
        while (m.find()) {
            String str = m.group();
            double value = Double.parseDouble(str);
            System.out.println( "#"+ i + " " + value);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one question. If I want to display the values with a number assigned to them, such a #1 0.00 /n  #2 0.45 /n ... and so on. How would I go about that? I have tried adding a int x variable in there and incrementing it after the print statement...but it won't increment.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I initialized my int x (or i), inside the while loop. Thank you for correcting my beginner mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can read with a scanner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
double a = sc.nextDouble();
```

Assuming that your input will be in a similar pattern, here is a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "# should be O: 0.00, A: 0.45, B: 0.35, AB: 0.20";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\ |,");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            sc.next();
        }
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this method earlier, it doesn't seem to work for me when I attempt to run. Gives me an error on the   double x1 = in.nextDouble();   line

Comment: @DLR: Are you sure? It worked for me. Did you use the line `sc.useDelimiter()` Also, I have a while loop to skip unwanted patterns.

Comment: Your code works fine if I separately run it, however it won't work on my program, I get the "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error

Answer (score 0):

After execution, `list` will contain all the doubles from the line.

```
double[] list = new double[line.length() - line.replace(".", "").length()];

for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int decimalIndex = line.indexOf(".");
    list[i] = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(decimalIndex - 1, decimalIndex + 3));
    line = line.replaceFirst("[.]", "");
}
```